# ANTLR4 : null parameter as a input

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have implemented a function in ANTLR4. Eg. - FUNCTION("A","B")

Grammar :

```
parse
  : block EOF
         ;

        block
         : 'FUNCTION' LPAREN  (atom)? COMMA (atom)? RPAREN 
         ;

        atom
        :   NIL                         #nilAtom
         | list                         #arrayAtom
         | type=(INT | DOUBLE)          #numberAtom
         | ID                           #idAtom
         ;

        list
         : BEGL array? ENDL
         ;

        array
         : array_element ( COMMA array_element )* # arrayValues
         ;


        array_element
        :
            atom # array_element_types
        ;

        COMMA : ',';

        BEGL : '[';
        LPAREN : '(';

        RPAREN : ')';
        ENDL : ']';
        NIL : '' | 'null';
    INT  : [0-9]+  ;

    DOUBLE  : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]*  | '.' [0-9]+ ;

    COMMENT  : '#' ~[\r\n]* -> skip  ;

    SPACE  : [ \t\r\n] -> skip  ;

OTHER  : .  ;
```

For input FUNCTION(,"B"),

Not able to differentiate between first and second parameter.

Getting "B" as first parameter.

Thanks for help.

Comment: btw, what is the purpose of the root element 'parse'? Why not start with block : 'FUNCTION' LPAREN  (atom)? COMMA (atom)? LPAREN  EOF

Comment: Had other grammar written. For question i have limited to this only.

Comment: 'FUNCTION' LPAREN  (atom)? COMMA (atom)? LPAREN  -> why it ends with LPAREN?

Comment: Changed it to RPAREN

Answer (score 0):

Try changing NIL : '' | 'null'; to NIL : 'null';
As you define atom with '?' it should take the input. I guess empty string is confusing.

For the function I would suggest grammar in this form to enable various parameters...

```
function : FUNCNAME LPAR par? (PARDELIMITER par)* RPAR;
```

Comment: Tried it. Its working for FUNCTION(null,"B") & can detect first and second param. But not in this case  FUNCTION(,"B").This is giving only one param

Comment: By the way, its parsing correctly. Unable to get both parameters in ANTLR visitor

Comment: FUNCTION' LPAREN  (atom)? COMMA (atom)? LPAREN is actually wrong.  Or do want NOT to support one or zero parameter functions?

Comment: I do not want it to be one or two params. Only two params is fine. Can we check it like this: (atom)? if it is null, put NIL instead in grammar itself. i tried it like this:  {$atom.text.equals(null)? $atom.text = NIL;}  Not working though

Comment: in that case its fine, just and idea, i would avoid '?' in that case, you know the parameter must be there

Comment: But the thing is unable to parse it when FUNCTION(,"B")

Comment: try put here exact grammar you are using, what you have pasted is not complete, bug is difficult to find, especially in antlr every character makes a difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157373/discussion-between-bond-and-divisadero).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert. Here one possible solution :

```
grammar Question;

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1554");}
    :   ( block NL)+ EOF
    ;

block
    :   'FUNCTION' list
    ;

list
@after {System.out.println("List " + $le.text); }
    :   LPAREN RPAREN
    |   LPAREN le=list_element RPAREN
    ;

list_element
@after {System.out.println("List element e1=" + $e1.text + " e2=" + $e2.text + " e3=" + $e3.text); }
    :   e2=expr ( COMMA e3=list_element )*
    |   e1=COMMA e3=list_element*
    ;

expr
    :   array                   #exprArray
    |   atom                    #exprAtom
    |   list                    #exprList
    ;

array
@after {System.out.println("Array a1=" + $a1.text + " a2=" + $a2.text); }
    :   LBRACKET RBRACKET
    |   LBRACKET a1=atom ( COMMA a2=atom )* RBRACKET
    ;

atom
    :   ID                      #idAtom
    |   type=(INT | DOUBLE)     #numberAtom
    |   STRING                  #stringAtom
//    |   NIL                     #nilAtom
    ;

COMMA    : ',' ;
LPAREN   : '(' ;
RPAREN   : ')' ;
LBRACKET : '[' ;
RBRACKET : ']' ;
//NIL      : '' | 'null' ;  // error(174): Question.g4:37:11: string literals and sets cannot be empty: ''
ID       : LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT | '_' )* ;
STRING   : '"' .*? '"' ;
INT      : DIGIT+ ;
DOUBLE   : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*  | '.' DIGIT+ ;
COMMENT  : '#' ~[\r\n]* -> skip  ;
NL       : [\r\n] ;
WS       : [ \t] -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
OTHER    : . ;

fragment DIGIT  : [0-9] ;
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

File `t.text` :

```
FUNCTION("A","B")
FUNCTION(,"B")
FUNCTION("A", ["B", "C"])
FUNCTION()
FUNCTION([])
FUNCTION([], "A")
FUNCTION("A", ["B", "C"], ("D", "E"))
FUNCTION("A", , "C")
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics t.text
[@0,0:7='FUNCTION',<'FUNCTION'>,1:0]
[@1,8:8='(',<'('>,1:8]
[@2,9:11='"A"',<STRING>,1:9]
[@3,12:12=',',<','>,1:12]
[@4,13:15='"B"',<STRING>,1:13]
[@5,16:16=')',<')'>,1:16]
[@6,17:17='\n',<NL>,1:17]
...
@76,160:159='<EOF>',<EOF>,9:0]
Question last update 1554
line 1:13 reportAttemptingFullContext d=2 (list_element), input=',"B"'
line 1:12 reportContextSensitivity d=2 (list_element), input=','
List element e1=null e2="B" e3=null
List element e1=null e2="A" e3="B"
List "A","B"
...
```

or :

```
$ grun Question question t.text
Question last update 1554
List element e1=null e2="B" e3=null
List element e1=null e2="A" e3="B"
List "A","B"
List element e1=null e2="B" e3=null
List element e1=, e2=null e3="B"
List ,"B"
...
List "A", ["B", "C"], ("D", "E")
...
List "A", , "C"
```

Variable e1, e2, etc are defined in the rule context and accessible in the listener.